# how to set scrolling = "no" at the iframe podio-webform-frame?

Tags: iframe, podio

How can I set `scrolling = "no"` at the iframe podio-webform-frame?

Unfortunately it's possible in fully-conforming HTML5 with just HTML and CSS properties

[view the automatic iframe generated by podio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvzV0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podio Webforms' iframe attributes are not customisable beforehand, but you can manipulate the attributes on it using, for example, JQuery.

Take a look at this SO answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083740/2904025

---

Example from Marcelo's code:

```
$('.podio-webform-frame').on("load", function() { 
  $('.podio-webform-frame').attr("scrolling", "no"); 
});
```

Comment: here is the solution: after function _podioWebForm.render("ID") enter:
 $('.podio-webform-frame').on("load", function() {
  $('.podio-webform-frame').attr("scrolling", "no");
 });

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as "accepted", so other people can find it in the future. You do that by clicking the checkmark button (✓) just below the up/downvotes

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("iframe").each(
     function(index, elem) {
         elem.setAttribute("scrolling","no");
     }
 );
```

I can recommend this solution, worked for me (compared to the one above which did not work). You can also add more attributes, just add a new line in that case, e.g.

```
elem.setAttribute("height","1159");
```